# Changing python version without breaking software center

Tags: 12.04, python-2.7, python3

I have been fiddling with my Python installation on Ubuntu 12.04 (I was having trouble installing a python library), and at one point my `python` command wasn't working. It turned out the symlink was missing (I must have removed it by accident lol), so I [made a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451417/broken-python-command) pointing to Python 3.2 (originally pointed to 2.7):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.2 /usr/bin/python
```

Problem: the software center and update manager weren't working:

```
~$ software-center
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 152
    print time.time()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guessed this was because I had changed the default python version (2.7->3.2), so I changed it back to 2.7. Now they work fine, but I'd still like to change the 'default' python version (i.e. the one called with `python` in the terminal).

Is it possible to do that in Ubuntu 12.04?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't change the symlink for `python` to point to Python 3 as you have already seen its consequences. And I would recommend you to get into the habit of calling Python 3 programs with `python3` as that would involve the least amount of trouble later on.

But if you insist on calling Python 3 on your Terminal using `python`, you may create an alias for it. Remember, alias is different than symlink. Edit `~/.bash_aliases` file (create it if it doesn't exist) to add the following in it:

```
alias python='python3.2'
```

Then restart your terminal and you would be able to execute Python 3 by calling `python`. This wouldn't break anything as changing the symlink does.

You may even add aliases like `alias py3='python3.2'` and then call `py3` to run Python 3. This is even shorter and less confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll just get used to using `python3` :)

Comment: This is *far* safer than making `/usr/bin/python` point to `python3` (on a release that ships with `python` pointing to `python2`), and I think it's usually okay, but it may not be entirely without problems. The shell has alias expansion enabled when it runs commands from `.bashrc`. If it contains `python` commands after `~/.bash_aliases`  has been sourced and they depend on `python` being Python 2, they won't work right. [That might have been what happened here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1247030), though [this very similar case](https://askubuntu.com/q/1251792/22949) makes me not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that:

- The Python programs that come with Ubuntu depend on `/usr/bin/python` being the default Python2 version of your distro. They will likely break if it is something else.
- [PEP-0394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) recommends that the `python` command calls Python2. Most Python programs will break if it calls Python3 instead.

Instead use `/usr/bin/python3` if you want to use Python3