# How can "A problem occured while checking for updates" be fixed when Terminal and Software Updater don't work?

Tags: command-line, updates, python, gnome-terminal, python3

I am currently facing a problem with the update checking error in Ubuntu 18.04.

Also after this problem terminal is not working or not opening. So I can't open the terminal as well as the software updater was not working currently.

I also tried through system setting for updates but still in system setting software and updates are not opening and working. What is the solution for this?

Can I please know how to recover back (my terminal and Software Updater aren't responding).
So that I can start using my terminal again.

[image: PIC for ref]

Apparently this happened when I tried to upgrade from python2 to 3.

Comment: If you cannot open the terminal, you can always launch a TTY terminal. Just press Ctrl+Alt+F3. You can also use the other F keys.

Comment: What do you get for `python -V; python3 -V`?  If default python is changed, tools that use it will have problems (like `apt`, `gnome-terminal` etc...)  Text terminals won't be impacted (only tools that use python)  Python3 is installed by default anyway on your system.  You need to reverse your change, and do it using non-python based tools (ie. skipping the higher-level tools, but `dpkg` and lower level tools)

Comment: *vinaytejab:* If you used [this technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/489531) or something every similar, and that is the only change you made, my answer to [How to get the terminal to work again? Terminal stopped working after changing default python version](https://askubuntu.com/q/1247030). However, if you didn't do that, or if you also changed what `/usr/bin/python` pointed to (whether with `ln` or with `update-alternatives`) or uninstalled Python-related packages, then [the OP's self-answer to that same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247063) is more likely to help than mine. cc @guiverc

Comment: I used TTY( which i had no idea about until u mentioned it) and ran the commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
and
sudo apt-get --reinstall python3-minimal
And it worked......Thanks Everyone!!!